# Probabilitic inequality for sum of squares of zero mean Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. standard normal random variables. How to show that there is constant $c>0$ such that for every $a_k>0$: $P(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kX_k^2>\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k+c\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2})>c$

Comment: Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we can normalize $a_{k}$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2 = 1$, which implies $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k \geq 1$.

Let $E = \{\omega \in \Omega \ | \ X_{k} > 2 \ \ \forall k\}$ be the event where all $X_{k}$ are at least two standard deviations to the right. Then, $P(E) = \Phi(-2)^{n} > 0$.

For any $a_k>0$:

$$E \subset F \equiv \left\{\omega \in \Omega \ \Bigg| \ \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k(X_k^2-1)>3 \right\}$$

Notice that $P(F)$ is your probability when $c = 3$, which only decreases in $c$. Thus, your probability is at least $\Phi(-2)^{n}$ when $c \leq 3$. Therefore, any $c < \Phi(-2)^{n}$ works.

(Notation: $\Omega$ is the sample space and $\Phi$ the cdf of a standard normal.)

I've only shown there exists such a $c$, a much more difficult question would be what is the largest possible $c$?

Comment: Clarification about the question, is it okay that $c$ depends on $n$?